# How can specified table data be animated within a table row with ng-animate?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, gsap

I'm using Angular's ng-repeat to generate a table with multiple rows.  I want to make specific table cells animate  when a user mouseovers the table row.

In this example case below, I only want to make the corresponding animated cells be visible (or opacity:1) when the row is mouseovered, but I don't want the the rows to change height (i.e. the row height should account for non-visible cell data).

I have tried CSS animation and ng-animate, but all of my attempts animate *all* of the rows' corresponding cells (e.g., in a multi-row table where the second column is animated, all cells in the second column will respond when the mouse is over any part of the table).

[Full example available in jsBin includes both Greensock TweenMax and css animation attempts.](http://jsbin.com/vupeju/121/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Relevant html (in this version, only the 2nd-column/red cells change visibility/opacity):

```
  <table class="view-container">
     <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.rows" 
         ng-click="fadeIt($index)"
         id={{$index}}>
       <td>index #{{($index)}}</td>
       <td class="animation red" hide-me="isHidden")>red background</td>
       <td class="animation blue">blue backgrounds</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Relevant js (using TweenMax)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.isHidden = false;
  $scope.fadeIt = function(id) {
    $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
  };
}]);

app.directive("hideMe", function ($animate) {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.hideMe, function (newVal) {
      if (newVal) {
        $animate.addClass(element, "fade");
      } else {
        $animate.removeClass(element, "fade");
      }
    });
  };
});

app.animation(".fade", function () {
  return {
    addClass: function (element, className) {
     TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity: 0});
    },
    removeClass: function(element, className) {
      TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity: 1});
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out how to do most of what I wanted.

The keys were to:

- include `display:block!important;` inside my `.animation` class
- place a content `<div></div>` within each `<td></td>`
- place all styling on the interior `<div>` *instead* of on the `<td>`, e.g.

  ```
  <td> <!-- no styles on the <td>; nothing between the <td> and <div> -->
      <div class="animation" ng-show="showDiv">
         <!-- all table data goes inside this div -->
      </div>
  </td>
  ```

My working example is available here - http://jsbin.com/wufehu/5/edit?html,css,output